# How to show only free/busy time in FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to use FullCalendar if I what to show on my site only free/busy time from my Google Calendar? I don't want to make this information public in Google Calendar settings.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and I solved creating a json feed.
I created a servlet that asked the Freebusy information from Google Calendar, put the information into a JSON, and made it available so I can fetch it from full calendar.

This is how my JSON look:

```
[
    {
        "id": "id",
        "start": "2013-10-20 02:00:00",
        "end": "2013-10-20 09:00:00",
        "title": "Busy",
        "description": "Busy",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "id": "id",
        "start": "2013-10-28 02:00:00",
        "end": "2013-10-28 05:00:43",
        "title": "Busy",
        "description": "Busy",
        "allDay": false
    }
]
```

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/